VSTO Outlook: HOWTO determine if the MailItem comes from a file saved previously in local and then open in Outlook
I have an Outlook VSTO add-in and I need to determine if the Outlook.MailItem being processed corresponds to a saved file on the local disk that has been opened in Outlook, regardless of the type of account configured (Exchange, IMAP, etc.). I need to differentiate it from a draft or any other type of email in any folder which is not a saved email.
Specifically, I need to detect unequivocally whether a MailItem was saved on the local disk and then opened in Outlook so that I can perform certain actions.
Here is a combination of things I have tried without success:

Checking the Explorer count
Checking the MailItem.EntryID
MailItem.ConversationID
MailItem.StoreID
Retrieving the MailItem based on its ID and then performing the actions only for a locally saved file

However, my logic is being executed for other selected emails in the inbox, drafts, etc., not just for locally saved files.
Below is the code snippet I have tried:
public bool IsLocalFile(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.EntryID) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.StoreID))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public string GetLocalFilePath(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
{
    Outlook.PropertyAccessor propertyAccessor = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
    try
    {
        return propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7D01001E") as string;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

        public bool IsInFolder(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder parentFolder = null;
            try
            {
                parentFolder = mailItem.Parent as Outlook.MAPIFolder;
                return parentFolder == null;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            return false;
        }

        public bool IsSaved(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder parentFolder = mailItem.Parent as Outlook.MAPIFolder;
            if (parentFolder!=null)
            {
                string folderPath = parentFolder.FolderPath;
                if (folderPath=="C:\\EmlFolder"||folderPath=="C:\\Attachments")
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            string messageContent = mailItem.Body;
            if (messageContent.Contains("Content-Type: multipart/related")||mailItem.BodyFormat==Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (mailItem.InternetCodepage==0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public string GetLocalFilePath2(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.EntryID)&&string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.StoreID))
            {
                Outlook.NameSpace outlookNamespace = mailItem.Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                Outlook.MailItem copiedMail = outlookNamespace.GetItemFromID(mailItem.EntryID);

                if (copiedMail!=null&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(copiedMail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F")))
                {
                    return copiedMail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F") as string;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

Then I check all above in a conditional:
if (mailItem.Session.Application.Explorers.Count == 0 ||
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mailItem.ConversationID) && !mailItem.IsDraft()) ||
    IsLocalFile(mailItem) ||
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetLocalFilePath(mailItem)) ||
    !IsInFolder(mailItem) ||
    IsSave(mailItem) ||
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetLocalFilePath2(mailItem)))
{
   // do stuff only in case it is a saved mail in local disk
}

Can anyone provide a reliable method to detect if a MailItem is a locally saved file opened in Outlook? I will highty appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

There is no way to do that as far as I know. There are no extra properties or any difference in the existing properties for a message opened from a local mailbox vs a standalone MSG file.
BTW, 0x370E001F is PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG, which is only present on attachments. never on messages. Don't know what 0x7D01001E is, but it is never present on any message I checked.

is not possible to get the local path from disk from which it is open and if not null then it is a saved mail?

No, There is no event that fires when an MSG file is opened - Inspectors.NewInspector will fire if the message is shown, but there is absolutely nothing that will distinguish MSG file based message from any other message based on its properties or any events or sequence of events fired by OOM.
